# Companion matrix for finding roots

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to solve a quadratic equation `x**2 + b * x + c =0`

My code is not giving the right answers on all occasions.

```
def solve_quad(b, c):

    b= float(b)
    c= float(c)
    import numpy as np

    # definition of companion matrix A of the quadratic equation 

    A = np.array([[0,-c],
                 [1,-b]])

    # roots of the quadratic equation are the eigen values of matrix A

    from numpy.linalg import eig

    e, v = eig(A)

    return e

solve_quad(0,1)
```

Testing the function:

```
from numpy import allclose

variants = [{'b': 4.0, 'c': 3.0},
        {'b': 2.0, 'c': 1.0},
        {'b': 0.5, 'c': 4.0},
        {'b': 1e10, 'c': 3.0},
        {'b': -1e10, 'c': 4.0},]

for var in variants:
   x1, x2 = solve_quad(**var)
   print(allclose(x1*x2, var['c']))
```

Some answers are 'True' while others are `False`. What is causing this?

So I am trying to use Newtons method to polish the roots, but I am not sure it will work that way.
    import numpy as np

```
def solve_quad(b, c):



   b= float(b)
   c= float(c)
   # defining the given function 
   def f(x):
       return x**2 + b*x + c

  # first derivative of the given function 
  def f1(x):
      return 2 * x + b

  # definition of companion matrix A of the quadratic equation  
  A = np.array([[0,-c],
              [1,-b]])

  # roots of the quadratic equation are the eigen values of matrix A

  from numpy.linalg import eigvals
  e = eigvals(A)
```

When b is extremely larger than c, there are numerical errors with the eigenvalues
so the idea is to use Newton's function to polish the roots we got using the companion matrix method 
so we are taking the roots from the eigenvalues of A as the first approximations of our true roots for the iteration process

```
   n_iter=0
   x_curr= e
   eps= 1e-5
   for v in e:  
      while n_iter < 20:

          x_next = e - f(e)/ f1(e)

          if (abs(x_curr - x_next) < eps):

              break

          x_curr = x_next
   return x_curr
```

Comment: numerical errors using eig at +/- 1e10

Comment: So what do I need to do to get rid of those errors?

Comment: your problem lies in computing the square root of `b**2 - 4*a*c` This dwarfes `4*a*c` and it disappears and results are ((-b-b)/2) and ((b-b)/2) so -b and 0. Testing your code this is the case for `1e9` and upwards.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe considered cheating, but since we know that the non-zero high value result is one of the roots, we can manipulate the second to be `c/x1`

```
def solve_quad(b, c):

    b= float(b)
    c= float(c)
    import numpy as np

    # definition of companion matrix A of the quadratic equation

    A = np.array([[0,-c],
                 [1,-b]])

    # roots of the quadratic equation are the eigen values of matrix A

    from numpy.linalg import eigvals
    #Used eigvals instead of eig because we are not using the vectors
    e = eigvals(A)

    #Checks for 0 roots where c is not zero, indicating a large root then forces the
    #zero value root to be c/(large value root). This is also not accurate but should
    #validate x1*x2 = c and returns non zero roots to avoid later on divisions 
    #or multiplications by zeroes.
    if any(v == 0. for v in e) and c != 0.:
        e[np.argwhere(e == 0)] = c/(e[np.nonzero(e)])

    return e
```

Another more accurate way to do it using Algebra is:

since `(1 + eps)**n = 1 + n.eps` for small eps we can rewrite:

```
def solve_quad(b, c):

    b= float(b)
    c= float(c)
    import numpy as np

    # definition of companion matrix A of the quadratic equation

    A = np.array([[0,-c],
                 [1,-b]])

    # roots of the quadratic equation are the eigen values of matrix A

    from numpy.linalg import eigvals
    #Used eigvals instead of eig because we are not using the vectors
    e = eigvals(A)

    # This is much more accurate although the results will appear to be the 
    #same and the multiplication is not exactly equal to c but the error 
    #here are due to the algebraic assumption we made and results are 
    #mathematical instead of forcing the result to be some value.
    if any(v == 0. for v in e) and c != 0.:
        eps = c/b
        e[np.nonzero(e)] += eps
        e[np.argwhere(e == 0)] = -eps

    return e
```

Comment: Is there a way to like use Newton's method to polish the eigenvalues https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

Comment: @Adewale I'm not sure of it, also it is never recommended to alter python module functions. You would have to re-write the `eig()` function completely. You can try that but so far if you try my second method it should work and is not actually cheating because we are only appending the loss of numerical precision at the end. I f you at least attempt to re-write eig() and post it, people would help out. But no one will re-write eig() function for you on demand.

Comment: @Adewale if you want a review of the math of how the assumption leads to the changes in the code I can share with you the formulas.

Comment: That would be great !!

Comment: we start with the scenario `b >> 4*a*c` then `sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c` => `(b**2 - 4*a*c)**0.5`  => `[b**2 * (1 - 4*a*c/b**2)] ** 0.5` => `b * (1 - 4*a*c/b**2) ** 0.5` This is similar tot eh assumption if `Epsilon = -4*a*c/b**2`. This leads to  `b * (1 - 0.5 * 4*a*c/b**2)` => `b * (1 - 2*a*c/b**2)`. We know `x = (-b  +/- sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c))/2*a` By replying with the above we get `x = (-b  +/- (b * (1  - 2*a*c))/2*a`. Leads to `x1 = -b/2a  + b/2a  -a*c/a*b  = -c/b #when a=1` and `x2 = -b/2*a - b/2*a + a*c/b*a 
 = -b + c/b  #when a=1`

Comment: I had a mistake with my second function, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

So I used Newton Iteration to polish the roots I got from the companion matrix and the code looks like this

```
def solve_quad1(b, c):
"""Solve a quadratic equation, x**2 + bx + c = 0.

Parameters
----------
b, c : float
   Coefficients

Returns
-------
x1, x2 : float or complex
   Roots.
"""
b= float(b)
c= float(c)
# defining the given function 
def f(x):
    return x**2 + b*x + c

# first derivative of the given function 
def f1(x):
    return 2 * x + b

# definition of companion matrix A of the quadratic equation  
A = np.array([[0,-c],
              [1,-b]])

# roots of the quadratic equation are the eigen values of matrix A

from numpy.linalg import eigvals
e = eigvals(A)

#When b is extremely larger than c,there are numerical errors with the eigen 
#values
#so the idea is to use Newton's function to polish the roots we got using the 
#companion matrix method 
#so we are taking the roots from the eigenvalues of A as the first 
#approximations of our true roots
#for the iteration process

n_iter=0
eps= 1e-5
x_curr1=[]

for v in e:
    x_curr= v
    while n_iter < 20:

        x_next = x_curr - f(x_curr)/ f1(x_curr)

        if (abs(x_curr - x_next) < eps):

            break

        x_curr = x_next
        n_iter += 1
    x_curr1.append(x_curr)

return x_curr1

#Example
solve_quad1(1000000,3)
```